# Import and install required plugin bundles in Eclipse PDE

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, bundle, pde

I created a new **plugin project** in Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers (Oxygen).

I now want to use (for example) [Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs) within my plugin, so I have to add this to my plugin dependencies.

**The solution that works**, but which is not satisfying at all:

- Add Jimfs to the Maven dependencies
- Copy Jimfs and and all its dependencies to a `lib` folder within my project. (I use a plugin for this)
- Add the `bin`-Folder to the `bin.includes` configuration in the `build.properties` file
- Add `lib/jimfs-1.1.jar` to the `Bundle-ClassPath` section of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

**What I want** and how I think this should work:

Add Jimfs to the `Required Plugins` section of [this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYy8q.png).
However, when I click `Add` the plugin is not available in the list.
How do I make it available as a plugin?

Also, if someone imports my plugin project then I want the required plugin to be automatically downloaded from the internet.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only code which is written to be an Eclipse plugin can be added as a dependency. The current method that you are using is correct for a non-plugin jar.

You could write a plugin which just contains the Jimfs jar. You would use the same procedure to include the jar and use `Export-Package` in the MANIFEST.MF to make the packages in the jar available.

Comment: Thank you. I will then try to create a plugin for Jimfs tonight.

In case of [wala.core](https://github.com/wala/WALA/tree/master/com.ibm.wala.core) I guess it should work out of the box because there is a `META-INF` directory but it doesn't show under the plugins-tab either. Why is that?

Comment: An Eclipse plugin requires a MANIFEST.MF with a number of entries such as `Bundle-SymbolicName` - if the code wasn't written to be an Eclipse plugin it won't have these.

Comment: Look at [com.ibm.wala.core](https://github.com/wala/WALA/blob/master/com.ibm.wala.core/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) for example. When I add `com.ibm.wala.core` to my maven dependencies than its still not available as a plugin. The only way I to get this as a plugin is to check out the source code but I can't expect someone who checks out my plugin project to manually also checkout third-party libraries.

Comment: You will have to package all the required plugins in to an installable 'feature' and make that available.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it drove me in the right direction I guess. :)